# How to make Xcode always show one register in variables watch list?

Tags: xcode, debugging, cpu-registers

E.g. I want to see rax register in variables list without showing all other registers, and I want to see it always, at any execution step. "Add expression" with simple "rax" value doesn't works (of course). lldb's command to show register value is `register read rax`, but I can't find out how to put it as expression correctly. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter expression as `$reg`, e.g. `$rax`.

[Xcode Debugging Guide: Monitoring the Value of an Expression](http://disanji.net/iOS_Doc/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/XcodeDebugging/220-Viewing_Variables_and_Memory/variables_and_memory.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007057-CH9-TPXREF111)

Comment: The link is dead and the mentioned expressions does't work.